# Pegar todas as tabelas de produtos e mover em apenas uma

Tags: php, mysql

Tipo eu tenho o banco produtos e as tabelas,quero que todas essas tabelas fiquem em apenas uma como posso fazer isso de jeito mais fácil?

Comment: Muito vaga a pergunta, você quer fazer isso direto no banco ou em PHP? Quer colocar todas as tabelas em uma só? Isso é, criar uma tabela com váaaaarias colunas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode fazer isso usando o comando ***JOIN*** no SQL como mostra o exemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

E, se quiser fazer o mesmo, usando PHP, basta rodar uma query sql (o join, no caso) no PDO.